# Deleting all iCal events and cleaning out iCal, so I can start new

Tags: ical

I had downloaded meetup iCal reminders, and now my iCal is inundated and there seems to be no way to remove meetup events from it. They just keep loading in, and I can't change it.

Moreover, I would basically like to reset my iCal so it is a blank slate and I can create the various events as I want.

Answer (score 2):

Close Calendar/iCal. In Finder, press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>. Type in "~/Library/Calendars". Press return. This folder contains all of the contents of your Calendar app on your Mac. Drag all of the contents to the Trash. Now launch Calendar/iCal again. It should be restored to its default settings.

Some caveats:

- Ensure that you are not syncing calendars from iCloud, Gmail, Exchange, etc. (You can check in System Preferences or Calendar/iCal Preferences to be sure).
- Do not empty the trash until you have ensured everything is working well. In a worst case scenario you can right click on items in the Trash and select "Put Back" to restore them if you want to undo all of this.